# How to fix the error "AirflowException("Hostname of job runner does not match")"?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm running airflow on my computer (Mac AirBook, 1.6 GHz Intel Core i5 and 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3). A DAG with several tasks, failed with below error. Checked several articles online but with little to no help. There is nothing wrong with the task itself(double checked).

Any help is much appreciated.

```
[2019-08-27 13:01:55,372] {sequential_executor.py:45} INFO - Executing command: ['airflow', 'run', 'Makefile_DAG', 'normalize_companies', '2019-08-27T15:38:20.914820+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/home/airflow/dags/makefileDAG.py']
[2019-08-27 13:01:56,937] {settings.py:213} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=40647
[2019-08-27 13:01:57,285] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-08-27 13:01:59,423] {dagbag.py:90} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/dags/makefileDAG.py
[2019-08-27 13:02:01,736] {cli.py:516} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: Makefile_DAG.normalize_companies 2019-08-27T15:38:20.914820+00:00 [queued]> on host ajays-macbook-air.local
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 522, in run
    _run(args, dag, ti)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 435, in _run
    run_job.run()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 213, in run
    self._execute()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/local_task_job.py", line 111, in _execute
    self.heartbeat()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 196, in heartbeat
    self.heartbeat_callback(session=session)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/local_task_job.py", line 159, in heartbeat_callback
    raise AirflowException("Hostname of job runner does not match")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Hostname of job runner does not match
[2019-08-27 13:05:05,904] {sequential_executor.py:52} ERROR - Failed to execute task Command '['airflow', 'run', 'Makefile_DAG', 'normalize_companies', '2019-08-27T15:38:20.914820+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/home/airflow/dags/makefileDAG.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1..
[2019-08-27 13:05:05,905] {scheduler_job.py:1256} INFO - Executor reports execution of Makefile_DAG.normalize_companies execution_date=2019-08-27 15:38:20.914820+00:00 exited with status failed for try_number 2
```

Logs from the task:

```
[2019-08-27 13:02:13,616] {bash_operator.py:115} INFO - Running command: python /home/Makefile_Redo/normalize_companies.py
[2019-08-27 13:02:13,628] {bash_operator.py:124} INFO - Output:
[2019-08-27 13:05:02,849] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2019-08-27 13:05:02,848[0m] {[34mlocal_task_job.py:[0m158} [33mWARNING[0m - [33mThe recorded hostname [1majays-macbook-air.local[0m does not match this instance's hostname [1mAJAYs-MacBook-Air.local[0m[0m
[2019-08-27 13:05:02,860] {helpers.py:319} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 40649
[2019-08-27 13:05:02,861] {taskinstance.py:897} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2019-08-27 13:05:02,862] {bash_operator.py:142} INFO - Sending SIGTERM signal to bash process group
[2019-08-27 13:05:03,539] {taskinstance.py:1047} ERROR - Task received SIGTERM signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 922, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 126, in execute
    for line in iter(sp.stdout.readline, b''):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 899, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
[2019-08-27 13:05:03,550] {taskinstance.py:1076} INFO - All retries failed; marking task as FAILED
```

A weird thing I noticed from above log is:
The recorded hostname [1majays-macbook-air.local[0m does not match this instance's hostname [1mAJAYs-MacBook-Air.local[0m[0m

How is this possible and any solution to fix this?

Comment: what is the output of `socket.getfqdn()` (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.4/airflow/config_templates/default_test.cfg#L52) in the python REPL and is it different from instance hostname?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule - the socket.getfqdn() is the correct hostname, but the task fails midway through execution with the hostname: 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa. No idea why the hostname would change during the task execution.

Comment: this can happen when you restart the airflow server and do not restart the scheduler

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem on my Mac. The solution that worked for me was updating `airflow.cfg` with `hostname_callable = socket:gethostname`. The original `getfqdn` returns different hostnames from time to time.

Comment: on airflow==2.1.0 this value changed to `socket.gethostname`
btw thx, help for me.